# Align centered wiith dcolumn when \multicolumn used

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

When \multicolumn is used in dcolumn, then there is misalignment in text and the heading. See the figure for more details.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption,ragged2e,array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{ D{.}{\cdot}{-1} }

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{margin=1.5cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{d{1} d{1} d{1} d{1} d{1} d{1}}
\toprule
kB/s_{um} & d/B & N_{c0} \text{ smooth base, smooth sides} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$N_{c0}$ rough base ($\alpha_{base}=1$, varying side adhesion factor $\alpha_{side}$)}\\
 & & \alpha_{base}= 0 \text{, } \alpha_{side}= 0 & \alpha_{side}= 0 & \alpha_{side}= 0.5 & \alpha_{side}= 1 \\
\midrule
0 & 0.0 & 5.144 & 5.157 & 5.157 & 5.157\\
  & 0.1 & 5.507 & 5.511 & 5.615 & 5.705\\
  & 0.2 & 5.758 & 5.762 & 5.977 & 6.124\\
  & 0.3 & 5.952 & 5.955 & 6.296 & 6.513\\
  & 0.5 & 6.222 & 6.224 & 6.850 & 7.231\\
  & 1.0 & 6.614 & 6.616 & 7.978 & 8.847\\[4pt]
5 & 0.0 & 8.357 & 9.818 & 9.818 & 9.818\\
  & 0.1 & 8.436 & 9.499 & 9.693 & 9.837\\
  & 0.2 & 8.204 & 9.097 & 9.437 & 9.631\\
  & 0.3 & 8.045 & 8.805 & 9.253 & 9.507\\
  & 0.5 & 7.899 & 8.439 & 9.042 & 9.414\\
  & 1.0 & 7.822 & 8.025 & 9.017 & 9.656\\[4pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bearing capacity factors $N_{c0}= q_u/s_{u0}$ for strip foundations}
\label{gourtable2}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
```

[image]

1- In the 3rd column, the text and numbers are not aligned properly. The numbers must be centered with the text. Same problem with 4th, 5th and 6th column.

2- In the `\newcolumntype`, the 3rd entry is specified as -1 because it is giving me a wider table but the extra space between 3rd and 4th column is not needed. Using #1 instead removes this, however it also removes the wider table.

What is the mistake I am doing in specifying the `\newcolumntype`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns are too wide, due to the large headers; I suggest to split them across lines and to use `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\tsub}[1]{_{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
}
\toprule
{$\si{kB/s}\tsub{um}$} &
  {\si{dB}} &
  {$N_{c0}$ smooth base,} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{$N_{c0}$ rough base, $\alpha\tsub{base}=1$,} \\
& & {smooth sides} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{varying side adhesion factor $\alpha\tsub{side}$}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
& & {$\alpha\tsub{base}=0$, $\alpha\tsub{side}=0$} &
  {$\alpha\tsub{side}=0$} &
  {$\alpha\tsub{side}=0.5$} &
  {$\alpha\tsub{side}=1$} \\
\midrule
0 & 0.0 & 5.144 & 5.157 & 5.157 & 5.157\\
  & 0.1 & 5.507 & 5.511 & 5.615 & 5.705\\
  & 0.2 & 5.758 & 5.762 & 5.977 & 6.124\\
  & 0.3 & 5.952 & 5.955 & 6.296 & 6.513\\
  & 0.5 & 6.222 & 6.224 & 6.850 & 7.231\\
  & 1.0 & 6.614 & 6.616 & 7.978 & 8.847\\
\midrule
5 & 0.0 & 8.357 & 9.818 & 9.818 & 9.818\\
  & 0.1 & 8.436 & 9.499 & 9.693 & 9.837\\
  & 0.2 & 8.204 & 9.097 & 9.437 & 9.631\\
  & 0.3 & 8.045 & 8.805 & 9.253 & 9.507\\
  & 0.5 & 7.899 & 8.439 & 9.042 & 9.414\\
  & 1.0 & 7.822 & 8.025 & 9.017 & 9.656\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bearing capacity factors $N_{c0}= q_u/s_{u0}$ for strip foundations}
\label{gourtable2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: true, was aware of the package but lacked the skills to create right commands. I added \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.75cm} so that the numbers can breathe. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly aligned on the specified alignment point!

```
N_{c0} \text{ smooth base, smooth sides}
```

does not have a `.` so it is taken as the integer part of a number in a `D` cell,  and the right hand edge is aligned with `.` in the column.

If you want centred alignment you need to specify that:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$N_{c0}$ smooth base, smooth sides}
```

---

For your second question -1 is OK (the extra space to the right of the third column will go once you fix the heading, it is just centering the `.` for what is currently specified as a very wide integer part).

In that case you may as well just use `d` with no argument. If you want to use `#1` and centre you need to specify `d{1.1}` for column 2 and `d{2.3}` in the other numeric columns (or whatever values your full data needs for *integer digits* `.` *decimal fraction digits* )